# Application get crashed when taken the picture in iPhone 4G?

Tags: iphone, crash

I have taken the photo from my device and resize the image and set it to my image view frame. But my apps get crashed some times after taken the photo(Using resize). Now i have taken the photo in iphone 4G. The application get crashed only, when the many application runs in the background(Multitasking). So how could i resolve this issue?, Other than the application doesn't crash at anytime. The only problem is, when many application runs in the background mode, while using the camera mode the apps get crashed. So please Help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you receive memory warnings?

Comment: @Max, The memory warning is " Received memory warning. Level=1 "

Comment: As i told :) That's probably leaks in your code. Run application with the Leaks tool.

Comment: I had the same problem with a simple application, the app was not leaking and it seemed that the device had few memory for my app. Restarting the device the application worked fine. Do you have some ideas? thanks

Comment: Hey just would like to add a link to my question (which is related to this).. cheers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309242/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-source-problem

Comment: check the device logs in Organsier, is it EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Once it's resized, do you release the original picture ? If not you have a minimum of 15MB of bitmap data in memory that do nothing. Sometimes, with many app in background, that amount can cause a crash. But i think you should receive a level 2 memory warning before crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app.

In my case, I missused dealloc instead of release at some points of my code like this.:

```
[label1 release];              // OK
[label2 release];              // OK
[label3 dealloc];              // Not OK

[super dealloc];               // OK
```

Check the code lines concerning with memory leaking.